# Ansible: Reference variable contents from variable name

Tags: ansible

I am trying to access the contents of a variable, from a variable name.   I've used ansible vault to create some passwords, and I am trying to create database users, like so:

```
postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    db: "{{ item }}"
    login_user: postgres_admin
    login_password: '{{postgres_admin}}'
    login_host: localhost
    login_port: 5433
    password: '{{ "{{item}}" }}'
loop:
   - artifactory
   - bitbucket
   - confluence
   - crowd
   - jira
```

In this case, I have a database user, which is the variable in the loop. The password for that user, is stored inside the (vault) variable name of that user.  In the password: field like I am trying to do a double reference.  It doesn't work.

I've tried a few more things, but this is my first run with Ansible and I don't want to go down the wrong path.  (I did not include the reference to the vault but it's at the top of the file, and it has been tested with a simpler tasks)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use lookup plugin *vars*. For example

```yaml
    password: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
```

With the introduction of the [collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html) the [documentation of the plugins is not available online anymore](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#plugin-list). See the documentation from the command-line

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

---

To make the code both more robust and user-friendly, I'd propose to rename the variables with the passwords. For example "*artifactory_passwd*" etc. Then, in the lookup, create the name of the variable dynamically

```yaml
    password: "{{ lookup('vars', item ~ '_passwd') }}"
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!  (I took your excellent suggestion as well)